# Tomcat roles with AJP and mod_auth_openidc

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ajp, mod-auth-openidc

My application runs on a tomcat (v8) and needs roles to work. Until now, I managed the users and their roles with a custom JDBCRealm which I configured in the server.xml. Also, until now I accessed the tomcat webserver directly.

Now I tried to use the Apache2 HTTPD with mod_auth_openidc and AJP. I want to let my users authenticate via OpenID Connect. Also, I wanted to let OpenID Connect handle the authorization. I created an Auth0-Account and used their service to test my application. It seems to work, after I added the attributes `tomcatAuthentication="false"` and `tomcatAuthorization="true"` to tomcat's AJP connector.

The `tomcatAuthorization="true"` attribute basically enables tomcat's authorization and lets it create a `GenericPrincipal` instead of a `CoyotePrincipal`, which has no roles.

Auth0 offers an interface on their website to add metadata to their JSON string in which I tried to add roles. Sadly, that didn't work.

Is there a way to let tomcat know which roles a user has using OpenID Connect and AJP?